# PDO вернуть ассоциативный массив

Tags: pdo, php

Добрый день, может ли в pdo ответ вернуть массив. Чтобы не делать такой костыль я про   $all = array();

```
function LoadAllActivePersonal(){

    $DBH = Registry::get('DBH');
    try {
        $all = array();
        $STH = $DBH->query("SELECT * from personal WHERE status = 0");
        $result = $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        while ($row = $STH->fetch()) {

            $all[] = $row;

        }

        return $all;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        print $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Советую получше изучить документацию. Вы почти **[угадали](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.fetchall.php)** с функцией.

```
$all = $STH->fetchAll();
```